# Add coverity scan to Qt app

Tags: qt, coverity

I'm trying to add [Coverity Scan static analysis](https://scan.coverity.com/) to my Qt project but I'm not able to get the result.

I download the coverity scan build tools and use the following command line:

```
cov-build --dir cov-int make
```

Which produces the following log:

```
...
my build log
...
[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
For more details, please look at:
    /Users/martin/dev/builds/ConsoleTest01-Desktop_Qt_5_3_clang_64bit-Debug/cov-int/build-log.txt
```

How can I go further?

I'm using Qt 5.3.2 under MacOS 10.9.

Comment: What does the log says?

Comment: the result is the log, I didn't put all the log which is the standard build log for the project

Comment: You mean that this log `cov-int/build-log.txt` is the one displayed ? That's not very verbose :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't read the docs carefully enough: https://scan.coverity.com/download?tab=cxx
I had to configure coverity first by running:

```
cov-configure --comptype clangcxx --compiler clang++ --template
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run qmake first, then you can run the cov-int command with make.

I found it easiest to run cov-int in my build- folder created by Qt-Creator.